# Duplicate and Canonical Issue?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url

I had question regarding ccTLDs, lets say, I have domain = domain.com but I found some one is copying my posts and paste at his domains at the same time, which seems to ccTLDs like domain.co.uk, domain.in (these are not my domains)

Additionally, we both have implemented the canonical tag, then how Google will determine which was the original post? Or to whom the content credit will be awarded?

Comment: *we both have implemented the canonical tag* Can you explain this further? I suspect I know what you mean, but want to make sure and not assume anything? Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Wow. That's really rude! Anyway, did you try turning off the auto canonical option in your SEO plugin? I did observe that Yoast does this auto canonical to each page. Canonical can only work if both of the domains are passing both rel="alternate" and rel="canonical".